# summarize from two differents rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

This is my starting df

```
test <- data.frame(year = c(2018,2018,2018,2018,2018), 
                    source = c("file1", "file1", "file1", "file1", "file1"),
                    area = c("000", "000", "800", "800", "800"),
                    cult2 = c("PBGEX", "QPGEX", "PBGEX", "QPGEX", "QPIND"), 
                    value = c(1000,2000,3000,4000,5000))

  year source area cult2 value
1 2018  file1  000 PBGEX  1000
2 2018  file1  000 QPGEX  2000
3 2018  file1  800 PBGEX  3000
4 2018  file1  800 QPGEX  4000
5 2018  file1  800 QPIND  5000
```

I need to get for each year/source/area the sum of value, for the fields PBGEX and QPGEX.
I was thinking of using `spread` and `gather` but I m losing many others columns (not show here).

This what I would except :

```
  year source area cult2 value
1 2018  file1  000 PBGEX  1000
2 2018  file1  000 QPGEX  2000
3 2018  file1  800 PBGEX  3000
4 2018  file1  800 QPGEX  4000
5 2018  file1  800 QPIND  5000
6 2018  file1  000 RDGEX  3000
7 2018  file1  800 RDGEX  7000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `filter` the rows where the 'cult2' are 'QPGEX', 'PBGEX', then do a `group_by` `sum` and  `bind_rows` with original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
    filter(cult2 %in% c("QPGEX", "PBGEX")) %>% 
    group_by(year, source, area) %>%
    summarise(cult2 = "RDGEX", value = sum(value), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    bind_rows(test, .)
```

-output

```
#   year source area cult2 value
#1 2018  file1  000 PBGEX  1000
#2 2018  file1  000 QPGEX  2000
#3 2018  file1  800 PBGEX  3000
#4 2018  file1  800 QPGEX  4000
#5 2018  file1  800 QPIND  5000
#6 2018  file1  000 RDGEX  3000
#7 2018  file1  800 RDGEX  7000
```

---

If we need a `prop`ortion column

```
test %>%
 filter(cult2 %in% c("QPGEX", "PBGEX")) %>% 
 group_by(year, source, area) %>%
 group_by(prop = value[cult2== "QPGEX"]/value[cult2 == "PBGEX"],
        .add = TRUE) %>% 
 summarise(cult2 = "RDGEX", value = sum(value), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
 bind_rows(test, .)
```

---

Or it can be also

```
library(tidyr)
test %>% 
   filter(cult2 %in% c("QPGEX", "PBGEX")) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = cult2, values_from = value) %>% 
   # or use spread
   #spread(cult2, value) %>%
   mutate(prop = QPGEX/PBGEX) %>% 
   select(-PBGEX, -QPGEX) %>%
   right_join(test)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#   year source area   prop cult2 value
#  <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#1  2018 file1  000    2    PBGEX  1000
#2  2018 file1  000    2    QPGEX  2000
#3  2018 file1  800    1.33 PBGEX  3000
#4  2018 file1  800    1.33 QPGEX  4000
#5  2018 file1  800    1.33 QPIND  5000
```

Comment: Thanks this is very good, but I also need the same calculation with a division instead of a sum, the result should be the result of QPGEX/PBGEX...Maybe you have an idea how to do this ?

Comment: @krifur can you check my update.  Is that the expected

Comment: oups sorry forget to say, my R version is not up to date, I can't use pivot_wider  :/edit: there is already two solutions, ok I m checking this, thanks again for help

Comment: @krifur you can change it to `spread`, updated with a commented line